# WWW::Mechanize::GZip triggering __DIE__ signal...why?

Tags: perl, gzip, mechanize, die

It's taken me a while to track down a sudden problem with my code, but it appears that WWW::Mechanize::GZip is somehow triggering my $SIG{**DIE**} handler.  Consider this code:

```
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize::GZip;

$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
   print "WTF???  WHY IS THIS BEING TRIGGERED?\n";
};

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::GZip->new();
$mech->get( 'http://ammoseek.com/' );

print $mech->content(), "\n";
```

Any idea why this would be happening?  And what can I do to prevent it?

Thanks,

-Mike

Comment: What's the message being passed to die?

Answer (score 2):

You can find out details of what/how died by having your `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler print:

- Error message (`$_[0]` in the handler)
- Stack trace (e.g. by calling `Carp::cluck`) from within the handler

As an alternative, use `onerror => \&func` parameter to WWW::Mechanize::GZip constructor to create custom error handler (assuming the error is not from Compress::Zlib). From [WWW::Mechanize POD](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.62/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

> onerror => \&func
>
> Reference to a die-compatible
>    function, such as Carp::croak, that is
>    called when there's a fatal error.
>
> If this is set to undef, no errors
>   will ever be shown.
>
> If this value is not passed, Mech uses
>   Carp::croak if Carp is installed, or
>   CORE::die if not.

Since WWW::Mechanize::GZip is a direct subclass of WWW::Mechanize, you can use the same parameters to constructor in it.

Comment: Setting onerror to undef doesn't work, unfortunately.  I emailed Peter Giessner, the module's author, and he suggested I simply create a local $SIG{__DIE__} to ignore all gunzip errors...

Comment: Probably comes from Compress::Zlib

Comment: @Mike: that will also ignore every other error, unless you customize your DIE handler a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there isn't a real exception, that is, that the code runs normally without the `$SIG{__DIE__}`, then something, somewhere inside that method call is probably using `eval BLOCK` to trap and recover from an error.  One of several problems with using `eval BLOCK` as an exception handler is that it triggers `$SIG{__DIE__}` even though it really shouldn't.

To avoid this, check that $^S is false in your `$SIG{__DIE__}`.

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    return if $^S;

    ...your error catching code...
};
```

See perlvar for more details.

BTW You can discover the details of the exception which is triggering this by printing @_.

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    print "SIGDIE caught @_";
};
```

Better yet, unless you really need a global die handler, use `eval BLOCK`.

```
eval {
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::GZip->new();
    $mech->get( 'http://ammoseek.com/' );
    1;
} or do {
    die "WWW::Mechanize::GZip failed and said: $@";
};
```

And have a look at Try::Tiny for a better exception handler.